# Integrating Box-Sdk with iOS application

Tags: ios, iphone, box-api, box, boxapiv2

I am working with an iOS application in which i have to authenticate with help of BOX-SDK for iOS and then upload images on Box. Firstly i used the sample app of BOX-API by Mr. lopopolo and upload images with that. Currently i want to integrate the api with my iOS application . i can work with the sample application but it uses storyboard . I am using XIB in my application so i get lots of issues. Can anybody tell me how to integrate Box-api with my iOS application.
I have to integrate box-api with my iOS app.Please help me out only with the authentication process. Please explain the steps for integrating the api so that i can authenticate with view controllers and xib not with the Storyboard.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: this may help https://github.com/box/box-ios-sdk-v2

Comment: @ramshad thanks for your words, but sir problem is with integrating with my iOS application. How to make authentication process from my controller. if u know please help me .

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use BOXContracts sample app to achieve your goal. it is not using Storyboard. https://github.com/box/box-ios-sdk-sample-app/tree/master/BOXContracts